# Do I need to add jar path in build.gradle?

Tags: ros, rosjava-core, gradle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to use some java classes from a jar file. If I import them I get error. I also export the CLASSPATH of the jar's path but does not help. Do I need to add the jar file path somewhere like in build.gradle or do I need to put this jar file in some other directory and access it there? Any hints please. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47312/do-i-need-to-add-jar-path-in-build.gradle???/) by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2012-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your jar files are in the `lib/` folder, you can add these lines to your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '**/*.jar')
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2012-11-06**:
Hi Martin, do you mean that I should make a lib/ folder inside the package and put it my jar file in there? "my.jar" file is in "home/robo/my_stack/jar/my.jar" while the build.gradle is "home/robo/my_stack/my_pkg/build.gradle". Can I use this path?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-11-07**:
Personally, I think it's cleaner if the jar file is inside your package, but you could of course also alter the path: `compile fileTree(dir:'../jar/my.jar', ...)`.

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2012-11-07**:
Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2014-01-18**:
I put my jar file in the build/install/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/lib where all the other jars were present. I also added the following line to my build.gradle file--compile fileTree(dir: 'build/install/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/lib', include: 'lin.jar') Do i need to make changes in the package.xml as well?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2014-01-18**:
@uzair: This answer was about the Fuerte, pre-catkin version of rosjava (and by 'lib' I meant a new subdirectory of your package). The Groovy/Hydro version of rosjava uses catkin and is much different, so I don't know how things work there. Best ask a new question.

**Comment by [uzair](https://answers.ros.org/users/8341/uzair/) on 2014-01-20**:
@martin : It all works now. I just had to add this in my build.gradle in the dependencies{}.
"compile files('lib/myjar.jar')"

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2014-01-20**:
In that case, my solution should also work (and you don't have to specify each jar file separately).